# SERIALIZABLE Transaction in JDBC remains SERIALIZABLE after the commit

Tags: oracle, jdbc, commit, serializable

I have a problem with transactions in JDBC and Oracle. I have the following code:

```
con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
con.setAutoCommit(true);
System.out.println(con.getTransactionIsolation());
con.commit();
System.out.println(con.getTransactionIsolation());
```

the problem is that both prints show: 8 (corresponding to the Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE attribute) but I think that it would have to print 8 and 2 Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED attribute).
Any help?

Comment: Committing a transaction is not going to change the isolation level.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think he wants to know why the transaction isolation level doesn't revert back to read committed after the commit (which terminates the transaction).  I guess the question is, is the setting of the isolation level a transaction-level attribute?  Apparently, it's an attribute of the conneciton, not a particular transaction.  This seems to be different than things work in SQL*Plus, where the isolation level is an attribute of the transaction itself.

Comment: That is true. In SQL developer when commited a SERIALIZABLE transaction, the new one is READ_COMMITED. I wonder why in JDBC it seems that the SERILIZABLE characteristic is a connection property instead a transaction property as in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the commit() call as just a transaction boundary. So after the commit you will be in a new transaction and you will still be in the same isolation level (SERIALIZABLE in this case).

By the way the JDBC specification dictates that calling commit() when auto-commit is true is illegal. This is mentioned in the JavaDoc for commit() which will throw an exception if auto-commit is enabled:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit--

You will get that behavior using the 12.1 Oracle JDBC driver. Prior versions didn't throw an exception.

Comment: Does it make sense? I mean, SERIALIZALE is a transaction property, but if we execute commit, a new transaction begins so it would have to be READ_COMMITED. Is there any place where it is documented? Thank you!

Comment: When the new transaction begins it's again in SERIALIZABLE isolation which means that you won't see changes that were committed through other connections. In Oracle the isolation is set on the session and will remain the same throughout the session unless you explicitly change it.